# Add service_account_scopes to Running Compute Engine Instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

[The document](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication?hl=zh-Tw#using) shows that service_account_scopes has to be added with "gcutil addinstance --service_account_scopes"

Is there a way to add service_account_scopes to running compute engine instances?

Answer (score 2):

The same documentation, also specifies that you cannot change or expand the list of scopes after an instance creation, unfortunately.

Hope that helps.
Cheers.